# Primary dealers in treasury auctions

Tags: government-debt, auctions

When the treasury or equivalent institution of a country auctions of government bonds there is frequently (i.e. in most countries) some sort of restriction on who can participate. The term [primary dealers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_dealer) refers to agents who participate in this primary auction with the intent of reselling the acquired bonds on the secondary market. Usually there is a gap between the bond price (or implied interest rate) of the primary and the secondary market so this is profitable.

Some papers on the phenomenon:

- [VALUING DEALERS' INFORMATIONAL ADVANTAGE: A STUDY OF CANADIAN TREASURY AUCTIONS](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23357234?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (JStor access needed)
- [Who Buys Treasury Securities at Auction](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6592976.pdf)

What benefit if any does the treasury derive from this setup, i.e. restricting auction access?

Comment: If the primary dealers have a privileged position, then there is value in being registered as a primary dealer, and so the Treasury or Central Bank can impose standards of behaviour (e.g. an expectation of reasonable participation in all bond auctions or open market operations) as a condition of maintaining that registration

Comment: @Henry How would this 'expectation' manifest itself and what benefit is it to the treasury? I am happy to participate in any auction as long as I can bid 0. There is definitely value to being registered as a primary dealer. This is the basis of my question.

Comment: If you bid $0$, I would probably not regard that as "reasonable participation".  So you would not stay on my list.  Since it is my list, I apply my discretion, and you could lose your privilege.

Comment: @Henry Okay. So is there a manifestation of these rules for staying on the list, are the rules written down somewhere? Unfortunately otherwise this seems very vague. (Not to mention speculative.)

Comment: @Henry And even if we allow for what are practically kickbacks to the Treasury it is not clear that current setup creates a higher payoff for the Treasury and the primary dealers combined than a non-restrictive auction would. If it does not then no amount of kickbacks that the primary dealers are willing to give can be sufficient to compensate the Treasury.

Comment: There are rules such as https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/pridealers_policies.html though you will find words like "reasonable" in them.  In effect primary dealers provide liquidity and information and markets even at times of crisis, which comes at a cost, one which countries such as the USA think is worth paying to get the increased financial stability it brings.

Comment: @Henry If you posted this link and a short summary as an answer I would upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(As requested in comments)*

Primary dealers have a privileged position, so there is value in being registered as a primary dealer.

The Treasury or Central Bank can impose standards of behaviour (e.g. an expectation of reasonable participation in all bond auctions or open market operations) as a condition of maintaining that registration. There are rules such as https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/pridealers_policies.html and you will find sections such as

> The New York Fed expects a primary dealer to:
>
> - participate consistently as counterparty to the New York Fed in its execution of open market operations to carry out U.S. monetary policy pursuant to the direction of the FOMC;
> - provide the New York Fed’s trading desk with market commentary and market information and analysis helpful in the formulation and implementation of monetary policy;
> - participate in all auctions of U.S. government debt; and
> - make reasonable markets for the New York Fed when it transacts on behalf of its foreign official account holders.
>
> In the selection process, the New York Fed will evaluate a prospective primary dealer with these expectations in mind.

In effect primary dealers provide liquidity and information and markets even at times of crisis, which comes at a cost, one which countries such as the USA think is worth paying to get the increased financial stability it brings.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in prices is compensation for market making activities in the secondary market. The market maker is the intermediary that connects buyers and sellers. You could compare the market maker to a store, the intermediary that connects the producer to the consumer. And like operating a store, market making is both costly and risky, and so it is fair that market makers are compensated for their troubles. Whether the *amount* of compensation is fair is an entirely different issue, and one for which I do not have a ready answer.

But this answer is unlikely to be in opening up primary markets. If primary markets were open, issuers of financial securities would have to carry the risk and costs of market making themselves. And why would they do that? There are no economies of scale for them: it's not practical to hold auctions that are open to thousands of bidders, particularly if all participants' details and credit scores need to be checked. Conversely, what's the benefit of having more bidders? Maximizing the return is all that matters to the issuer, and it is not at all obvious that the difference in price would outweigh the additional costs.

Comment: How is making the primary market, were prices are determined through auctions, any less difficult than making the secondary market? That is if the treasury can cope with the first, why can it not cope with the latter?

Comment: @denesp You misunderstand, it's not about difficulty but about cost and risk. Is the comparison with a store unclear?

Comment: I understand the comparison but doubt is accuracy. The Treasury has an online auction interface. As such it has a direct link to buyers. Why is there need for an intermediary? (Here I thought you would argue proper prices, but I argue those are set by the auction algorithms.)

Comment: It seems as though you are looking for an argument as to why the Treasury couldn't possibly integrate the markets. This is the wrong way to look at it, because they can. The question is why they would want to. By employing private (and more efficient) market makers, they avoid a bunch of unnecessary costs and risks. Don't you think that if the Treasury yield would be higher if they would function as their own market maker, they would do so?

Comment: I think there a lot of occasions when the optimal solution is not reached simply because of institutional inertia. I think in this case the Treasury could reach a higher yield by integrating the markets. As Henry pointed out in his answer there could be considerations other than yield, such as liquidity, but I am not sure the market integration would not solve this problem as well.

Comment: "I think in this case the Treasury could reach a higher yield by integrating the markets."
Yet you have no evidence at all for this assertion. You are unwilling to accept the value of market makers in financial markets. I don't see it as my job to convince you, since it has little bearing on your original question. I can, however, recommend some further reading if you ever doubt your conviction: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-financial-and-quantitative-analysis/article/the-microeconomics-of-market-making/1862B3B03A305605321B99F0A78CE199

Comment: I am somewhat confused by your antagonism. I have no evidence. I also have no evidence to the contrary, hence my question. Thank you for your link, I will have a look at it.

Comment: It's not meant to be antagonistic. I'm just observing that your responses (and, likely, interpretations) are guided by a certain conviction, and that this bars you from even accepting the framework of my answer (e.g. "the Treasury is inefficient" rather than "the activity is risky and costly"). This was not obvious from the way you asked the question, and if I'd known this beforehand I probably wouldn't have bothered answering. I'd be happy to be proven wrong and learn something new, but arguing with a stranger merely for the sake of arguing is not my idea of a good time.